# Can't get cucumber tests running in headless on OSX - works on ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, macos, cucumber, headless

In my `env.rb` file, I have this:

```
if ENV["HEADLESS"] == 'true'
    require "headless"
    @headless = Headless.new
    @headless.start
end
```

This works fine in Ubuntu, but not in OSX. The browser still pops up. What do I need to do to make this work in OSX?

Comment: What web driver are you using?

Comment: @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security]

Comment: Have you already got this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headless won't hide most OSX applications. This is the intended behaviour. Headless is meant to run graphical applications on a Linux server.

See https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless/issues/31#issuecomment-8933108 for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the default firefox installation on OSX doesn't use X11 for its rendering. It uses....cocoa?

Macports has an install but I haven't tried it yet. http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=firefox-x11